# Delete own query on data explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Is it possible to delete or at least hide your own data explorer query when you know you've only been testing something and don't want it to show?

Comment: I am new to Data Explorer and today edited the same query a few times. Now I found that older versions of the same query are stored as separate ones in my profile http://data.stackexchange.com/users/8597/michael-freidgeim. It is confusing and it should be an ability to remove the draft versions of the same query.

Comment: While you're trying to figure out the right syntax and column names it seems to permanently publicly archive every tweak. I avoid ever writing any queries on the Data Explorer because of that exceptionally stupid behavior, and instead have to hope there is already a query that does what I want, but oh wait, I won't find it if there is one because there's a thousand other queries with hard-coded single-use values sitting around, that someone used three years ago one Tuesday afternoon. It's awful.

Answer (score 18):

No, you cannot currently hide queries that you've ran, but better query organization tools are on the todo list that will hopefully address this and other concerns.

We keep track of all executed queries to monitor for abusive behaviour, so following any changes you'd only be able to at most "hide" them (similar to deleted posts here), but from the user perspective that should amount to the same thing.

Just to clarify, since people keep commenting about it – this is on the todo list, just be patient.

Comment: Well using data explorer you can test whatever query even creating your own temporary data that hasn't got anything to do with any of the StackExchange site. This means that you can write some queries that you don't wan't to be public.

Comment: Arguably in that case the solution is just "Don't do that", then.

Comment: Another reason is also that not all queries are usable or even valid. Some of them are worse *duplicates* that were superseded by a better variant. Take these two for example: [a better version](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61442/average-tag-count-per-question) and a previous [worse one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61441/how-many-tags-per-question). The better version has all the data plus average data. I would be glad to delete the worse version. Why I created two of them is a different Q but this likely happens to others as well.

Comment: Basically just like questions and answers can be deleted so could be these. Or voted to be closed as duplicates or similar.

Comment: I am actually interested in why you created two queries instead of just revising the first one, in case it indicates a problem with the workflow. As far as hiding queries goes, I'm still not really a fan of the idea for various reasons, though [waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) may feel differently.

Comment: The real answer is *Lack of experience with data explorer* so I opened the same thing in the other browser comparing results... I know, but I consider myself an average user, so I suppose this is not a seldom thing. Hence the *close/hide/delete* feature question.

Comment: For some personal reason, I really want to delete queries I have written. It's counter-intuitive that I don't have the right to delete what I create

Comment: I wish to delete my queries, because I was playing with someone else query, and didn't realize I created "revisions" of his query, it just feel wrong that those queries are available to anyone while it was just learning DB schema. I believe each query run should be private, and only those explicitly "saved" (no option as of today) or those "created" should be available to public after establishing a good query title

Comment: Some people just dislike clutter. It's the reason git has `--amend`, Gmail (eventually) added Delete in addition to Archive, and Macs have so few ports on the side.

Comment: If you want to keep track of executed queries, log them on your side, and delete old logs after 60 days or something. It's not useful to permanently archive and display old broken/junk/test/single-use queries for everyone else.

Comment: Has this been implemented? I came to ask the same question but didn't want to create a duplicate.

Comment: "this is on the todo list" - is this still the case? Or can this be marked as [tag:status-declined] so people won't build false hopes?

Comment: ANy News about its availability still?

Comment: I've started renaming my old queries `[Deleted]` to get around this, although it just gives me a load of queries called `[Deleted]`

Comment: 2020 is here. Is it still in the todo list?

Comment: Now we're in 2024 and it seems we already cannot do that

Answer (score 14):

No, you cannot, but you *can* edit the name and description so as to no longer be meaningful (e.g. Name = "Delete me", Description = "select 1").

Comment: I used an empty name and I added a comment `-- DELETE THIS QUERY` as description. At least I see empty lines in **edited** section on my profile.

Comment: It is **important** to note that if you forked someone else's query, edited it, and now want to delete it ***don't*** **edit the name** because that edits and updates the name of the query that you forked from - altering the description (code) is OK since that won't affect the original from which you forked. That probably is a bug @TimStone as it's unwanted behavior.

Comment: @Rob Just great! Thanks for a warning. Even question revisions on SE preserve their titles...