# How can I remove queries from my data explorer profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, data-explorer

My data explorer profile contains some throwaway or duplicate queries. They make it harder to find the queries that I want to find later. Can I remove queries from my profile?

(If the answer is no, this is a feature request.)

Comment: You could favourite the ones you want to keep hold of?

Comment: @Matt I want to keep most of the ones I've written. I'd just like to weed out the junk. I prefer to reserve favorites for other people's queries.

Comment: [Delete own query on data explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122324) covers the support piece, so I switched this to a [meta-tag:feature-request].