# Query the Data Explorer without saving the query

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Is there any way to run a query against the Data Explorer without having that query be saved forever? I'd really like to be able to do some experimentation without polluting everyone's searches with my half-assed SQL.

Comment: In a strict sense no, because it's important to know who ran what. But better query management from a UI perspective is on the todo list.

Comment: @VotetoClose It's more about identifying abusive users if necessary (people running expensive queries to slow down the system, etc.), but for the normal user there should be a way to hide junk queries.

Comment: Related [How can I remove queries from my data explorer profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135997)

Comment: @TimStone I would consider this a dupe, as adding ability to delete is equivalent to being able to query without saving. Isn't it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's two sides of the same coin, perhaps. I don't feel that strongly about it either way, so vote as appropriate.