# Return reputation from answers & get a permalink of the results in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: support, reputation, answers, data-explorer

1. How do I get a link to send to someone, so even non-logged in users can see the results directly:

   [image: screenshot showing results]

   ...without needing to click "Run Query" or anything?
2. Is there any way to get reputation from only answers? There is a `reputation` column, but I want to exclude the reputation collected **from questions**.
3. How can I delete the old queries from my profile, which I no longer need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Query Results with the same parameters are [cached for a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139098/158100). In those cases you don't need to click the button *Run Query*. The query results are shown immediately.
   If the query isn't cached, there is no option to run the query with just following a link. In this case the button *Run Query* need to be clicked. Anonymous users also need to solve the reCaptcha before they run a non-cached query.
2. You need to [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/895642?user=2377343) the votes tables (votetypes 1 (accept), 2 (up-mod), 3 (down-mod) and 9  (bounty) are of interest.

This query will probably do it:

```sql
    select sum(case v.votetypeid
            when 1 then 15 -- accepted
            when 2 then 10 -- up vote
            when 3 then -2 -- down vote
            when 9 then v.bountyamount -- bounty earned
            else 0
            end
            ) [answer rep]
    from posts p 
    inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
    where posttypeid = 2 -- Answers
    and p.owneruserid = ##user?int:2377343##
    and p.communityowneddate is null -- only non community wiki answers
    and v.votetypeid in (1,2,3,9)
```

3. That is not possible at the moment but there have been feature requests that ask for the same feature to be added, for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135997/how-can-i-remove-queries-from-my-data-explorer-profile) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122324/delete-own-query-on-data-explorer)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you provide me example of 1. Please give me any link as i could see the results directly. (try yourself in Private tab, i cant make your suggestion to work)

Comment: @T.Todua if you have run the query the results will be available for everyone when they follow [a query link](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/895642?user=2377343). If you try `http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/[any number here]` in private mode, you (most likely) don't get any results and when you click *run Query* you have to solve the captcha first.