# Is there a way to delete some of my own queries?

Tags: support

I've composed a few queries and then I found that there is not an option to remove some of those.

I [searched a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=delete%20my%20own%20query) but no luck.

[image]

Is there a way to delete some of my own queries?

Comment: Or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122324/delete-own-query-on-data-explorer