# Can I merge duplicate data.SX queries I've written?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I've written identically-titled SX data explorer queries, by mistake. Can I merge them (including merging their star count)? If not, can I make the system forget about one of them (i.e. delete one of them)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete own query on data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122324/delete-own-query-on-data-explorer) - so, 2x6-8 years; or make this a Feature Request. There are quite a few duplicates to this question. The *answer* is that if you somehow know that you won't write a good query don't log in while you are working on it; then log in to save the working version (answer courtesy Glo).

Comment: @Rob: Non-deletability is a problem (a bug I would say), but I was talking about merging dupes, not arbitrary deletion.

Comment: @Rob: Assuming identical everything - a trivial reconciliation with stars added up. Otherwise, assuming Q1's change history is a prefix of the change history of Q2 - keeping Q2. Otherwise, if the only divergence in change history is titles, than choosing Q2 as in the above but some way of asking the user (dialog box even?) for a title of the merged query.

Comment: That would be a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info), and not tagged "support".

Comment: @Rob: That's if there's no mechanism/procedure for merging, which I didn't know. Make your comment an answer, which I can accept, then I'd ask for a feature.